# joins- how to pass the parameter in stored procedure to execute a join query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, join

I have used joins to get data from two tables under common name, as

```
SELECT userValidity.UserName, userValidity.ValidFrom,userValidity.ValidUpTo,userValidity.TotalPoints, 
persons.SenderID
FROM userValidity
INNER JOIN persons
ON userValidity.Username=tbl_persons.Username
```

But I need to execute this query with only the username which I pass as parameter in stored procedure..

How to pass the username in stored procedure in this joins.

```
alter procedure GetNameIDUserInformation
(
@user varchar(max)
)
as
begin

SELECT userValidity.UserName, userValidity.ValidFrom,userValidity.ValidUpTo,userValidity.TotalPoints, 
persons.SenderID
FROM userValidity
INNER JOIN persons
ON userValidity.Username=tbl_persons.Username 
end
```

In this SP, where I have to pass the user parameter to get the single row of my user record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you just add `WHERE userValidity.Username=user` to the query? :

```
alter procedure GetNameIDUserInformation ( @user varchar(max) ) as
begin
    SELECT userValidity.UserName,
    userValidity.ValidFrom,userValidity.ValidUpTo,
    userValidity.TotalPoints, persons.SenderID
    FROM userValidity
    INNER JOIN persons
    ON userValidity.Username=tbl_persons.Username end
    WHERE userValidity.Username=user
```

If you get a syntax error around `user`, consider using a different name, as `user` is a reserved keyword in some RDBMSes.